# Subclipse icon error (not under version control)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I have recently reinstalled Subclipse and next to some of my packages within some projects are a question mark indicating that the project is not under version control.

However, it is under version control; .svn files are up to date and command line works fine. If I commit from subclipse, it'll go through fine and the question mark will disappear. However:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Entry already exists svn:'/home/user/workspace/ProjectA/src/packageA/file.java' is already under version control
```

Comment: @Hannes > 1.7 svn version

Comment: You may be having issues with the carriage return conversion - if this is set to Native and you are running under windows then this can confuse things.

Comment: Another possibility is case sensitiveness. In an mixed environment windows vs rest of the world, this can happen annoyingly often. What can help is to commit the file, delete it locally and revert.